# Right margin error in Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, margin

I am in the midst of a webpage design with Bootstrap. I positioned an absolute `<div>` (transparent text overlay) on an image that I coded to be responsive within the Bootstrap column framework. My text overlay in the absolute `<div>` align with the image on the left margin but runs over on the right margin (i.e., doesn’t fit within the set Bootstrap columns on the right). Any suggestions for how I can get the right border of the transparent text overlay to align within the column framework so it is responsive with the image?

See https://cgriffith5.github.io/research.html

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-5 container">    
        <img src="assets/img.jpg" class="img-rounded" style="width:100%"> 
        <div class="overlay">Text</div>   
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative; 
    max-width: 410px; /* Maximum width */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center it */
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute; /* Position the background text */
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0; /* At the bottom. Use top:0 to append it to the top */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
    color: #f1f1f1; /* Grey text */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your HTML code like this:

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md-5 container">
      <div style="position: relative"> <!-- Make a div and give it a position of relative -->
         <img src="assets/img.jpg" class="img-rounded" style="width:100%"> 
         <p class="overlay">Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

We are wrapping the whole div containing the img and overlay as position of relative and inside that making the overlay with position of absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page you posted at https://cgriffith5.github.io/research.html, one solution is to change the width of the .overlay div from 100% to

```
.overlay {  
...  
width: calc(100% - 30px);  
...  
}
```

The default Bootstrap padding on a column is 15px left and right, so reducing the with of .overlay by 15px + 15px compensates for this and makes it the same width as the image.

Here's a live demo:  https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/pLQRja

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you so much, very grateful for a solution.